# Integer solutions of a complex equation

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

The topic of this question is about **integer solutions** of a complex equation.

Let $m,r≥1$ two integers and $α,β∈(0,1)$. Let $f$ be an analytic function but without known or closed formula. I know that $f$ is of order $1$. I have an equation of the form:

$(m+1)f(1+(m+1)α)-(r+1)f(1+(r+1)β)=0$

Here $α,β$ need not to be equal. I notice that

$(i+1)f(1+(i+1)α)-(j+1)f(1+(j+1)β)=0$

for all integers $i,j≥1$. However the equation can give other solutions.

The exercice seeks one thing: 
Find conditions in which $m=r$ is the only solution of this equation.

Comment: Quite unclear. Is this the question: you want conditions on $f$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$ such that the only integers $x\ge2$ and $y\ge2$ satisfying $xf(1+x\alpha)=yf(1+y\beta)$ are given by $x=y$?

Comment: @  Gerry Myerson: Yes, this is my exact question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sufficient condition is that $f(z)$ be increasing on $z\ge1$. For suppose $\alpha\le\beta$. Then $x\lt y$ implies $x\alpha\lt y\beta$, $1+x\alpha\lt 1+y\beta$, $f(1+x\alpha)\lt f(1+y\beta)$, $xf(1+x\alpha)\lt yf(1+y\beta)$, with a similar argument for $\alpha\ge\beta$.